# Android OpenGL: Bitmap.getHeight() > actual height

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
```

My background.png has a size of 512x512px

I use BitmapFactory to load the Bitmap of the background resource file.

**The strang thing:**

```
Log.d("bitmap height", bmp.getHeight() + "px");
```

*always* returns 768px.

How is this possible?

My openGL is setup like this:

```
width = 480;
height = 800;
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0f);

gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitmapFactory will scale the bitmap when the bitmap's DPI doesn't match the screen's DPI. The solution is to set the inScaled option to false:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.background, opts);
```

Answer (score 2):

768 / 512 = 1.5
This is the factor used for your screen resolution.

Comment: Can I change this factor, or do I have to render all sprites with lower size? Where does this factor come from?

Comment: I suppose you're asking that because your background exceed screen bounds. In my app I used android:scaleType="fitXY" for the background ImageView and I forgot about png dimensions. Is this useful?

Comment: No, not really. My "background" is a "normal" sprite. I don't make any difference between a background or an other image sprite. I am using OpenGL to draw these sprites, so I can't make any settings like "scaleType" or what every :/

Comment: Well, I suppose you're putting your png in the drawable-mdpi folder and you're using an hdpi device (240 dpi). For this reason your bitmap is scaled x1.5. Let's have a deep look at that: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Im going to check this out.